# Python - How to sort a list of colors based on a color's "distance" from a source color in 3D (r, g, b) space?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Here are the basic steps to an app I'm writing in Python:

1. Generate a list of random colors
2. Create a mapping of each of those colors, indexed by that color's distance to a "source color" in 3D (r, g, b) space. (For instance, orange (255, 150, 0) is closer to red(255, 0, 0) than dark blue (0, 0, 100). By now, I have a list of tuples of the format (distance, color).
3. Sort that list of tuples based on the distances I had calculated (from lowest, to highest).
4. Retrieve a list of the sorted colors

Here is my function, and I get the following error: **TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_*getitem*_'** on the line **sorted_by_dist = sorted(colorMap, key=lambda tup: tup[0])**

```
# Sorts a list of colors according to distance from the source color
def sort_colors(colors, source):
    colorMap = ()
    sortedColors = list()
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        dist = dist_3d(colors[i], source)
        colorMap = colorMap + (dist, colors[i])

    sorted_by_dist = sorted(colorMap, key=lambda tup: tup[0])

    for (d, c) in sorted_by_dist:
        sortedColors.append(c)

    return sortedColors
```

Assuming my dist_3d() function is correct and returns an integer value (it is, and does), what am I doing wrong? I don't understand.

Comment: Color distance among RGB triplets is fundamentally wrong, independent of code being correct or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. It's also irrelevant to the overall application... right now it's just a placeholder function while I get other pieces of my code working. It happened to by the first "thing to do with colors" that came to my mind as a placeholder.

Comment: @mmgp, why do you say that? Lab color space might be better, but RGB isn't too shabby.

Comment: @MarkRansom really ? What is your distance function for RGB ?

Comment: @mmgp: `sqrt((r1-r2)**2+(g1-g2)**2+(b1-b2)**2)` and the `sqrt` is optional.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't understand how it isn't obvious considering this equation. Suppose you have to apply a very simple filter, let's say a median filter using a 3x3 window. So you have 9 triplets to order, let's consider you order them according to a common triple (0, 0, 0), now you apply the filter. For simplicity, the neighbors are either pure red, pure green or pure blue. How do you determine each of them you will pick to replace the central value ?

Comment: @mmgp since the distance is equal they're equivalent and it doesn't really matter which you pick. If you want to be consistent you apply a secondary sort criteria. How would you do it?

Comment: @MarkRansom of course it matters, and of course they are not equal (they are very 3 different colors). Suppose you have g, b, r, g, b, r, g, b, r, as the neighbors. They are already "ordered", since they give the same distance, so you pick the blue one to replace the mid (which doesn't change anything). Now in another window you have r, b, g, r, r, r, r, g, b. And now it turns out you pick red. How does that make any sense ? I'm stumped by your observations. What second sort criteria do you have in mind ?

Comment: @mmgp well if it doesn't work for you don't use it. In the application I had, mapping an image to a palette, RGB distance worked great - and it really didn't matter which one you picked if they were equal distance. The original question never mentioned median filter.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm aware it didn't mention median filter, and median filter is only an example too. Virtually for any task involving color ordering, RGB will give meaningless results. I don't know what is your exact application, but I wouldn't reduce colors to form a palette by means of euclidean distance in RGB, there are much better ways.

Comment: We can continue this discussion somewhere else if you want. I raised the initial issue because I'm worried that people would see this question and think "Great idea! I'm going to order my RGB colors too so I can perform operation X", which is unlikely to be a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your `colorMap` as a big single dimensional tuple, with the first index being an `int`. So your `lambda` is being passed an `int` and then you try to index into it.

You probably want a list of tuples:

```
colorMap = []
...
    dist = dist_3d(colors[i], source)
    colorMap.append((dist, colors[i]))
```

In terms of an approach to sorting colors, I have actually used a [`kdtree` module](http://code.google.com/p/python-kdtree/) for this, loaded up with all my RGB tuples. Then I can ask it for N closest colors to a given color tuple:

```
from kdtree import KDTree

colors = [(10,10,10),(250,50,5),(100,50,20)]
query_color = (175, 25, 50)

tree = KDTree.construct_from_data(data)
# query the 2 closest colors
nearest = tree.query(query_point=query_color, t=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had never heard of k-d trees before... shocking! I'll most likely wind up using this as I work more and more with colors.

My app works as designed now, with the caveat that my dist_3d doesn't ACTUALLY do the right thing, but it's working perfectly as a placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because `tup` is an `int`. `__getitem__` is the name of the `[]` operator.

But, it looks like all your function is doing is sorting a list of colors, based on distance from some reference color. And, you already have `dist_3d` implemented. Given that it works, then sorting your colors is much simpler. Sort them in place:

```
colors.sort(key=lambda color: dist_3d(color, reference_color))
```

or as a new list:

```
sorted_colors = sorted(unsorted_colors, key=lambda color: dist_3d(color, reference_color))
```

No need for all that tuple-building and looping and stuff in your function, as I can tell.